# Uploading .kml files to WordPress

Tags: wordpress, kml

I'm trying to upload .kml files to WordPress. I had this working at one point but the latest WordPress update seems to have broken it.

I'm using this function

```
function my_myme_types($mime_types){
$mime_types['kml'] = 'application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml'; //Adding kml extension
$mime_types['kmz'] = 'application/vnd.google-earth.kmz'; //Adding kmz files
return $mime_types;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'my_myme_types', 1, 1);
```

I get this error when uploading

"Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons."

Answer (score 15):

For KML/KMZ files to be properly supported, you'll have to use `text/xml` and `application/zip` instead, because WordPress compares the declared MIME type to the 'real' detected MIME type (see function `wp_check_filetype_and_ext` in `wp-includes/functions.php` for more details)

```
function add_upload_mimes($mimes) {
  $mimes['kml'] = 'text/xml';
  $mimes['kmz'] = 'application/zip';
  return $mimes;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'add_upload_mimes');
```

**Update (2019-02-28)** : kml is detected as text/xml and not application/xml, changing the code accordingly should resolve the issue described in the comments below.

Comment: This no longer works as of version 5.1. Been racking my brain trying to find a fix.

Comment: In my case with wordpress 5.0.3, the solution is to use the mime-type application/xml

Comment: Thanks for the 2019 update :) `text/xml` finally works!

Answer (score 1):

This may be related as of after the latest wordpress update:

Trying to upload xml file and getting the same error message, updating *upload_mimes* WordPress filter hook doesn't work as well as using some file uploading or mime type managing plugins which essentially using the same filter hook.

Solution: update wp-config.php and add in the following line

***define( 'ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true );***

and then remove this line after uploading the files to avoid potential security risk